# Can we re mineralize our teeth?

Tags: dentistry, minerals

Is it possible to mineralize and make our corroding teeth strong back again?

- What should one do?
- Which food items will help?

Answers will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is possible to remineralize teeth without cavitation. I am unsure what you mean by corroding, but cavities cannot be fixed by remineralization. Products can inhibit damage and harden intact and decalcified enamel.

- [Remineralizing tooth paste.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10686854)
- [Xylitol](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14700079)

[Low Cariogenic diet](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18517060)

> Initial caries lesions without cavitation of the surface can
> remineralise (heal) under conditions of low cariogenic diet and good
> oral hygiene. However, once the surface has broken and cavitation
> occurred, there is no alternative to restorative dental therapy
> because remineralisation is no more possible.

Avoiding things like some beverages that break down teeth is a good thing to remember when prevention teeth problems.

Answer (score 0):

This is only my personal experience, not solid evidence.

I have had holes in my teeth for 10 years without any worsening. I try to eat a balanced diet low in modern refined processed foods, with natural meats like wild game.

Also I listen to my body, if I get pain in my teeth, it is a reminder to clean better and stop eating sugar, the pain goes away if I do this.

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). Reliable references are [strongly encouraged](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) on this site, since they are the only way for other users to verify the validity of an answer. You can always [edit] your question to add some. Thanks!

Comment: I removed that weak reference. It originated from a dentist called Weston Price. His work it not regarded as very reliable, but still probably worth reading if you also read the criticisms of it, and come to your own conclusion.

Comment: @NickCollier Thanks for your post, I see you edited your post however now it has no references. Finding reliable sources would be appreciated as it helps support your statement. Good luck. See the help center or ask here for any questions.

Comment: @Pobrecita I can delete it if you like. I am new here so just getting used to what is appropriate to write. I don't have any reliable sources at the moment

Comment: I am not going to tell you to delete your post and I apologize if I came across mean. However, post with reliable sources are preferred here and that is what prompted all the messages. It is not exactly a rush to find the sources and I realize that you are new to Stack Exchange. I would suggest you take the site tour and read the Help Center as these might benefit you.